# How to install python package without copy everything into lib/site-packages?

Tags: python, deployment, installation

I want to develop a common python package, I got other packages depends on it.  For example:

- packageA/
- packageB/
- packageC/
- commonPackage/

packageA, packageB and packageC can all be executed directly, but they are all depend on commonPackage.  I want to install the commonPackage into lib/site-packages, but I don't want it copys the source code. Instead, I want it creates a commonPackage.pth in lib/site-packages with the path of where the commonPackage at.  So that when I modify commonPackage or update it from SVN, I don't need to install it again.  Here comes the problem,  how can I write the setup.py or use the options of python setup.py install so that it would do what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oops, I just find exactly what I want [here](http://packages.python.org/an_example_pypi_project/setuptools.html).  The develop command of setuptools do what I said.  Here you type

```
python setup.py develop
```

It creates .pth rather than copying everything into site-packages.

Answer (score 1):

You can always take a look at virtualenv which will allow you to create a python environment for each of your projects - this is the ideal way to develop/build/deploy your app without having load up your site-packages directory with all and sundry.

There's a good tutorial here:

http://iamzed.com/2009/05/07/a-primer-on-virtualenv/

Good luck !